# {list}.size() == 0 or {list}.isEmpty() ? what is more performance effective?

Tags: java, java-8

Appreciate if you could explain the performance efficiency of the following 2 methods to check the emptiness of List in Java.

- {list}.size() == 0
- {list}.isEmpty()

Comment: There is no difference.  This is not worth caring about.

Comment: Actually, in the general case there **can be** a performance difference.  But you need to look at the specific `List` implementation to understand what it will be.  (For the standard `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` there is no difference.)

Comment: There is a general principle: don't optimize things unless you *know* that optimization is necessary.  And they only real what to know that (accurately) is to benchmark and profile *at the application level* ... before you start optimizing.  Then just optimize the hotspots.  Beware of premature optimization.  It is a waste of time and effort.

Comment: There are only two possible scenarios 1) implementations where `isEmpty()` as just the same as `size() == 0` (where the current size is stored in a field) and 2) implementations where `size()` has to perform an actual, potentially expensive counting operation but `isEmpty()` can be much cheaper, as the actual count is not needed. In general, there is no reason not to use `isEmpty()` when you want to know whether a collections *is empty*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For common list implementations, they're exactly the same. Looking at the source code of OpenJDK's [`ArrayList`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java), the implementation of `isEmpty()` is as follows:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}
```

And the implementation of `size()`:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

In general, this type of *nano*-optimization is almost never worth caring about. If a more readable standard method is available, use it.

When in doubt, check the Javadoc, the source code of the JDK you're using, or perform a micro-benchmark.

Comment: `ArrayList` is just one implementation. A counter-example would be `ConcurrentSkipListMap`…